# How do I copy and paste the tooltip error message that pops up in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA automatically shows a red line if it cannot resolve some entities or it detects an error. Is there a way to copy and paste the content of that tooltip?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With eclipse I use the <kbd>f2</kbd> to get the information.

I used the idea version 14.1.4 and use this way to copy the tooltips.

You can click the error line and the info will display, now you can right click to copy this error info.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It was always a frustrating hit and miss trying to select the text from the tooltip.

Answer (score 6):

Mouse shortcut:

1. Hover mouse over error in editor to bring up tooltip
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click on error message inside tooltip to copy it to clipboard

For step 1 you can also bring up the tooltip for the current carret position by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. For step 2 there does not seem to exist a keyboard shortcut at the time of writing (for IntelliJ 2018.1), see also [IDEA-65636](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65636#comment=27-1804502).

Answer (score 5):

If you stumbled upon looking for solution for Linux version (and none of the above worked for you, like for me) click ctrl+alt+left mouse button on the tooltip, and you'll get its content into the clipboard :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the tooltips don't offer a way to get that information from their context alone.

You could traditionally compile it instead via Build -> Compile and get the error message that way, instead.  You can then select *this* text and do with it what you wish.

Comment: That works, except if you want to report a bug to Jetbrains that is about wrong error messages in the editor...

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report on this since 2011 (!) . Feel free /encouraged to vote for having the bug fixed:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65636

> IDEA-65636 I can't copy text from tooltip, though I can select it

Though honestly JetBrains infrequently gets around to non super critical bug fixes.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed!